# Spring Boot 2 Interceptor resolves `/login' on every request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Inside Spring boot security I'm trying to redirect server side the login page within Spring boot automatically to an overview page if I detect that the user is already logged in. The login screen should only show when the user is logged out.

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer
{

   @Override
   public void addInterceptors( InterceptorRegistry registry )
   {
      registry.addInterceptor( new LoginInterceptor() ).addPathPatterns( "/login" );
   }
```

Inside LoginInterceptor I have:

```
   @Override
   public boolean preHandle( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler ) throws Exception
   {

      Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
      String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
      System.out.println(url);
      if( auth.isAuthenticated() )
      {
         response.sendRedirect( "/my/overview" );
         return false;
      }

      return true;
   }
```

However, even if I am logged in, the debugger seems to think that I'm still on the /login route. Does spring boot route every request through `/login` for checking authentication? How do I achieve my aim of not resolving the login page unless the user is logged out?

Comment: My bad, read it differently. But why do this in an interceptor and not just in the controller that selects the view to render? You don't really need an interceptor for this.

Comment: @M.Deinum  The controller that selects the view to render is tucked away within Spring security. It's not exposed as its own method or indeed controller per se. It's all handled within the config within Spring security from what I can tell.

Comment: There is no controller by default but rather a filter, if you define a different `loginUrl` you can attach a controller which selects the view or does this logic.

Comment: @M.Deinum - my understanding is that if you override this behaviour you lose lots of other spring goodies and have to implement other stuff that Spring does for you? i.e. it's not just a matter of over-riding the default loginController and you are done, particularly when it comes to Oauth handling etc, which this app also has within it. I could be way off the mark on that however.

Comment: There is no default loginController but only a filter which by default renders a hardcoded login page. If you set a URL and map a controller to it you can do whatever you want.  You don't loose anything.

Comment: @M.Deinum - ok cool - pop an answer below with the detail of the same and I'll give that approach a spin, least you'll get the internet points if it works out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what was happening here was 'anonymousUser' was being returned for isAuthenticated, and thus the authenticated method wasn't working. The redirect for unauthorised accounts kicked in making me think that everything was going through login route when it was actually just the security doing its thing. 
checking for principle null was the way to go instead.

```
 if( auth.isAuthenticated() && principal != null )
 {
      response.sendRedirect( OVERVIEW_PAGE );
      return false;
 }
```